# Completely autonomous traversal of a planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have to program an autonomous robot to traverse through a grid given in the following figure.
 But the main problem is that the nodes to visit is not known beforehand, it will be received by the bot in real time.
 E.g.- after reaching the node 19, the bot now has to go to node 6. The shortest path(19-17-7-6) can be calculated by Dijkstra algo but i don't know how to make the robot traverse that path.
Any idea for an algorithm that can help in autonomous traversal by the bot ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZekYu.png

Comment: Why can't you use trivial breadth-first search?

Comment: Dijkstra's seems like overkill since the edges don't have weights. I don't see what exactly your question is. Do a breadth-first search to find the path, and then tell the bot to take that path. What's the problem?

Comment: If you don't need to reach a destination vertex from a source vertex by a shortest part then you can make a bus of your robot: fix a cycle going through all vertices and direct the robot to endlessly follow this cycle. :-)